# how to add text wrap for long text in react-data-grid?

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

i have a react data grid and one cell have long paragraph text. i need to wrap text in color dynamically

check example in CSB

https://codesandbox.io/s/rdg-cell-editing-forked-nlvsr?file=/src/index.js